# is there any way I can avoid reading old files from old folder with Apache Beam's TextIo watchForNewFiles(Duration, condition)?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Use Case: During dataflow job start up we should provide initial file name to read data and later on it should watch for new files in that directory and it should consider all remaining old files as already read.

Issues:

Approach 1:

```
PCollection<String> readfile = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://folder-Name/*").
                    watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardSeconds(10),
                           Watch.Growth.afterTimeSinceNewOutput(Duration.standardSeconds(30))));
```

If we are using like this its considering old files as new files for this dataflow job and reading all those files in that folder

Approach 2:

```
PCollection<String> readfile = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://folder-Name/file-name").
                    watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardSeconds(10),
                           Watch.Growth.afterTimeSinceNewOutput(Duration.standardSeconds(30))));
```

Its reading only this particular file and not able to read upcoming new files

can anyone please suggest the approach to achieve my use case?

Answer (score 1):

The watchForNewFiles() function will always read all files matching the filepattern, both existing and new.  In your second approach, the file pattern is only one file, so you just get that.

However, you can use the lower-level building block transforms in FileIO to accomplish what you need.  The following code will just read files written after the pipeline starts:

```
PCollection<String> lines = p
  .apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("gs://folder-Name/*")
    .continuously(Duration.standardSeconds(30), afterTimeSinceNewOutput(Duration.standardHours(1)))
  .setCoder(MetadataCoderV2.of())
  .apply(Filter.by(metadata -> metadata.lastModifiedMillis() > PIPELINE_START))
  .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
  .apply(apply(TextIO.readFiles()))
```

You can change the details of the Filter transform to whatever precise condition you need.  To also include specific older files, you can read those with a standard TextIO.read().from(...) and then use Flatten to combine that PCollection with the continuous set.  Like this:

```
PCollection allLines =
  PCollectionList.of(lines).and(p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://folder-Name/file-name)
  .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
```

Comment: Hi Danielm, Thank you. This approach seems to be correct match for my use case but even though I am using setCoder(MetadataCoderV2.of()) the metadata.lastModifiedMillis() is coming as "0" (default value). can you please suggest how can I resolve this?

Comment: hmm what version of Beam are you using?

Comment: Using beam 2.28.0

Comment: have tried with beam versions 2.28.0 and 2.26.0 but it haven't worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clarify your Use Case, do you provide a file name to read ? or a file pattern ? What is the number of files expected ? Should you really use a Dataflow streaming pipeline ? Doesn't a Cloud Function answer your need ? What is your issue ? Files get read again when you restart your pipeline ?

You can, [as suggested by danielm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808084/2508468) use FileIO to fetch and filter on file metadata in order to know which file was added after the pipeline began.

If you provide a file pattern, then all file will be read once by the pipeline. There's no way to keep a State between pipelines if you not code it yourself, so when you restart the pipeline you will read again all the file matching the pattern.

If you want to avoid that, you can manually move old files to another path between stopping the old pipeline and starting a new one.

You could also consider is consuming [GCS notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#events) on file creation with PubsubIO and use this event to know which file to treat in your pipeline.

A good practice though is to have multiple folders that reflects the status of the files:

- input
- processing
- failed
- succeed

This way you know the state of each file. You can put files to treat in the `input` folder, and inside your pipeline move the file to its corresponding state folder.